# My app is working fine on my real device but it is not working on the emulator and other devices

Tags: android

My app is working fine on my real device but she is not working on the emulator and other devices except my device and I don't know why.

As I write the app working only on my phone and everything is good but when I try to check the app on another phone or in the emulator it doesn't work.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.matan_gesta.gestamain">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".GestaMainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".GPS_Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Google_Gesta"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_google__gesta"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="Gesta" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Facebook_login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

</application>
```

the errors from the logcat:

```
01-19 14:02:10.777 5387-6114/? E/Gmail.LabelManager: Unable to get label ^sq_ig_i_personal for account account:21453719 01-19 14:02:10.777 5387-6114/? E/Gmail: Couldn't find label: ^sq_ig_i_personal 01-19 14:02:10.824 2003-2003/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null 01-19 14:02:11.134 2485-6127/? E/AccountsChangedIntentOp: exception while subscribe: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 6000 milliseconds for awgr@2e3c018[status=PENDING] 01-19 14:02:11.420 2003-2003/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null 01-19 14:02:11.428 1616-1628/? E/SyncManager: Job params not found for 109473 01-19 14:02:11.820 2003-2324/? E/ctxmgr: [NetworkUtil]No active synchronizable contexts. 01-19 14:02:12.557 2003-2324/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: , App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller fbl: Long live credential not available. at fbm.b(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:10) at fbm.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:50) at ezw.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:37) at gnu.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:7) at gnu.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:155) at gmu.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:2) at gms.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:17) at gms.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:6) at cob.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:25) at cob.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:80) at ewz.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:6) at ewy.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:2) at ewy.e(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:6) at ewy.d(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:1) at eww.b(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:1) at mqa.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:1) at mon.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:3) at dfo.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:54) at dax.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:2) at dav.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:3) at muq.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:6) at mvc.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:26) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) at nak.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 01-19 14:02:13.117 2485-2748/? E/ProcessCheckinRequest: CheckinNowTaskTag : Checkin Succeeded: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #1): 01-19 14:02:13.531 2003-2324/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (WriteInterestRecordTask) got error statusCode=-1. com.android.volley.VolleyError: Unable to obtain auth token - is the device online? at dfo.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:62) at dax.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:2) at dav.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:3) at muq.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:6) at mvc.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470:26) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) at nak.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951470) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 01-19
```

Comment: If there's no logcat, then you're silently ignoring errors, or you've logged nothing. Please do so and add a [mcve] to your post

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you could post few more details like emulators API version and also about your real device. These kind of things can happen because of different way to provide permissions in different API versions.

You are using location reference that doesn't work on emulators.

Comment: emulators API is nexus 5_api24 my real device is meizo m3

Comment: OK i got it I guess you need to login to the google account in emulator and also need to generate new authentication token for this device. And one more thing bluetooth doesn't  not working in emulator so it was showing null  pointer exception.